# Rotating a view in objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, tweak

I am trying to make the multitasking switcher open in landscape mode all the time... even when the phone is being held in portrait... Any ideas? The class is "SBAppSwitcherController" and I'm calling the method "viewDidAppear"

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Supported Interface Orientations to only landscape modes.  To do that, you go to your project in the Project Navigator.  Then, you will see the Supported Interface Orientations header. Click the dark icons referring to portrait mode to make them light.  Then your program will only be in landscape mode. So, if I know what you are saying, you are done!

Comment: This question is asking about how to **change** the SpringBoard app itself (written by Apple) to change its orientation support.  Your suggestion only works for apps that you write yourself, and for which you control the project settings.  This is what's referred to by the `tweak` tag on the question ... modifying behaviour of existing iOS software.